# Cuntz semigroups of basic C*-algebras

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

I am doing some research related to Cuntz semigroups, and I am trying to find concrete examples in simple cases. In [one paper that I found](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.0483.pdf), it says the following (p.103):

> "[...] $A_i$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of $r_i$ matrix algebras. Then [...] $\operatorname{Cu}(A_i) = \overline{\mathbb{N}}^{r_i}$ [...]"

Here, $\operatorname{Cu}(A)$ denotes the Cuntz semigroup of $A$. This suggests to me that the following two facts are true:

1. For any $n \geq 1$, we have $\operatorname{Cu}(M_n(\mathbb{C})) = \overline{\mathbb{N}}$
2. For any C*-algebras $A,B$, we have $\operatorname{Cu}(A \oplus B) = \operatorname{Cu}(A) \oplus \operatorname{Cu}(B)$

However, in my search for references, I have not been able to find these facts stated plainly.

**My question is**: are these two facts true? If so, could someone provide a reference which includes proofs of them?

Comment: Both are true. Here are some hints for proving them: (1) A positive operator in $M_n(\mathbb C) \otimes \mathcal K(\ell^2) \cong \mathcal K(\ell^2)$ will be mapped to its rank in $\overline{\mathbb N}$. (2): Use the definition of $\mathrm{Cu}(D)$ as $(D \otimes \mathcal K(\ell^2))_+$ modulo Cuntz equivalence, and that $(A\oplus B)\otimes \mathcal K(\ell^2) \cong (A\otimes \mathcal K(\ell^2)) \oplus (B\otimes \mathcal K(\ell^2))$.

Comment: @JamieGabe Thank you, that helps! I'd still like to have a reference for these facts, if you happen to know any, so that I can reference them when writing a paper.

Comment: (1) can be found as a (very special) case of Theorem 2.45 of [Ara, Pere; Perera, Francesc; Toms, Andrew S. K-theory for operator algebras. Classification of C∗-algebras]. Although this is not how you should think of it. It is an easy consequence of the elementary fact that positive compact operators are diagonalisable. 
(2) I doubt you'll find a reference with a proof (at most people will just write "note that" or "clearly"). It really just follows immediately from what I wrote.

Comment: @JamieGabe Would you mind answering another short question? In some references (namely Blackadar's "Operator Algebras"), $M_\infty(A)$ is the space of infinite matrices with finitely many nonzero entries. But in other references, I've seen that the Cuntz semigroup is the quotient of $M_\infty(A)$ by Cuntz subequivalence. Are these different usages?

Comment: The original definition of the Cuntz semigroup (due to Cuntz) is $W(A)=M_\infty(A)_+/\sim$. The modern definition of the Cuntz semigroup (due to Coward-Elliott-Ivanescu) is $\mathrm{Cu}(A)=(A\otimes K)_+/\sim$. These are closely related (we have $\mathrm{Cu}(A)=W(A\otimes K)$) but not equal. For example, $W(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathbb{N}$, while $\mathrm{Cu}(\mathbb{C})\cong\overline{\mathbb{N}}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty\}$.

Comment: @HannesThiel That is very helpful, thank you! I was getting very confused while reading and comparing older papers to newer papers.